# Changing the darkness of a pattern / fore_color in easyxf

Tags: python, colors, xlwt

Is there a way to change the other values such as the darkness value when using predefined color names in easyxf?  For example, in Excel when we choose a theme color from Fill Color dropdown, it shows a pallet for each color with various darker values, e.g.

```
Tan, Background 2, Darker 10%
Tan, Background 2, Darker 25%
Tan, Background 2, Darker 50%
Tan, Background 2, Darker 75%
Tan, Background 2, Darker 100%
```

or

```
Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 80%
Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 60%
Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 40%
Olive Green, Accent 3, Darker 25%
Olive Green, Accent 3, Darker 50%
```

Can this be done in easyxf using the color names, without having to figure out the RGB values?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me.

```
    import xlwt
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    xlwt.add_palette_colour("custom_colour", 0x21)

    # RGB for Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 40%
    workbook.set_colour_RGB(0x21, 155, 187, 89)
    st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour custom_colour')
    sheet.write(count, 0, ilc_map[epic], st)
```